# Can not type in a text box using python selenium

Tags: javascript, python, selenium, webdriver

I'm trying to send keys to the following textarea html using python selenium:

```
<div class="spk-c spH-d"><div id="gwt-uid-23" class="sppb-a">
<div class="sppb-b spk-b">For example, flowers or used cars</div>
<textarea rows="2" aria-labelledby="gwt-uid-64 gwt-uid-23" id="gwt-debug-keywords-text-area" class="spk-a sppb-c">
</textarea>
</div> 
<div role="alert" class="error" style="display:none"> Input contains a keyword that is too long. </div> <div class="error" style="display:none">Your product or service description can't exceed 1,000 words. Remove some words and try again.
</div>
</div>
```

and I get this error:

```
selenium.common.exceptions.ElementNotVisibleException: Message: Element is not currently visible and so may not be interacted with
Stacktrace:
```

here is my code:

```
textarea='textarea[id="gwt-debug-keywords-text-area"]'
element = WebDriverWait(driver, 15).until(lambda driver : driver.find_element_by_css_selector(textarea))
driver.find_element_by_css_selector(textarea).send_keys('plumbers')
```

Can you please help me out? It's been bugging me for a while. The html is from google keyword planner.
Thank you

Answer (score 1):

You can use expected conditions to wait for the text box visibility

```
WebDriverWait(driver, 15).until(expected_conditions.visibility_of_element_located((By.ID, 'gwt-debug-keywords-text-area'))).send_keys('plumbers')
```

> Edit

You need to switch to the `iframe` with the textarea in order to interact with it

```
# by the frame id attribute
driver.switch_to.frame(id)

# by the frame name attribute
driver.switch_to.frame(name)

# by the frame webelement
frame = drive.find_element(...) # locate the frame
driver.switch_to.frame(frame)
```

And to switch back

```
driver.switch_to.default_content()
```

Comment: I get a error NameError: name 'By' is not defined trying your method.

Comment: @RobertWest You need to import it  `from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By` and expected conditions `from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions`

Comment: ok...now I have another error: AttributeError: 'visibility_of_element_located' object has no attribute 'send_keys'

Comment: @RobertWest try it now.

Comment: Now it just waits for 15 sec and trows me an error: selenium.common.exceptions.TimeoutException: Message:

Comment: same thing my friend Error: selenium.common.exceptions.TimeoutException: Message:

Comment: @RobertWest check if you have `frame` or `iframe` tag in the html.

Comment: yes there is a iframe in the html...but is so full of javascript that I don't understand from where. Again the page is adwords keyword planner tool, is there any way to complete that textarea?

Comment: @RobertWest You need to switch to the `iframe` first. I added to my answer how to do it.

Comment: the textarea is not in the iframe...there are frames in the html...but the textarea is not inside any

Answer (score 0):

The problem may not be with your selenium code, but the workflow for using the tool.  I am not familiar with this adwords keyword planner, but when I did a Google search for the id of that text area and selenium, I came across some [github code](https://github.com/Startup2013/bars/blob/master/view_data/utils/parse_ad_words.py) that looks like it is enabling the text area first:

```
browser.find_element_by_id("gwt-debug-splash-panel-find-keywords-selection-input").click()
browser.find_element_by_xpath("//textarea[@id='gwt-debug-keywords-text-area']").send_keys(keyword)
```

Comment: I tried also your solution. Every time I try to select that textarea even with xpath or css selectors or just by id...I get the same error. Can't figure this one out.

Answer (score -1):

Try to use `JS` code to make element visible before sending text:

```
driver.execute_script("document.getElementById('gwt-debug-keywords-text-area').style.visibility = 'visible';")
driver.execute_script("document.getElementById('gwt-debug-keywords-text-area').style.display='bloc‌​k';")
```

Let me know if any exceptions occurs

UPDATE

If you want to send text to text area using `JS` you might need to execute following:

```
driver.execute_script("document.getElementById('gwt-debug-keywords-text-area').innerHTML='Here is some text';")
```

or

```
driver.execute_script("document.getElementById('gwt-debug-keywords-text-area').value='Here is some text';")
```

Comment: I just tried your method before driver.find_element_by_css_selector(textarea).send_keys('plumbers') and still the same error  Message: Element is not currently visible and so may not be interacted with. Maybe using javascript to change the change the textarea filed value? I tried lots of methods none seem to work.

Comment: Just tried your code...there are no errors but it doesn't send any keys, the textarea stays empty.